# How to change the highlight variable color in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, ide, color-scheme

I am talking about this background color underneath `droparea` variable, see screenshot:

[image]

My color scheme would be perfect if I get just that resolved.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `Category` you are looking for is `Mark Occurrences`, but it is language specific so you won't find it under `All Languages`. You will see it when you change the `Language` to `Java` for instance. Then you have to change the `Background` field on the right hand side.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the original highlight color is really really annoying when using dark themes.

Comment: Just a note for Groovy: Netbeans 7.3 does not allow to change that, however, Netbeans 7.4b allows it.

Comment: I want to point out that when I changed the color and pressed apply nothing happened. The current color didn't changed. But when I selected a new entity then the new color applied.

Comment: nb 8.0.2 and the color change didnt appear, sad sad

Comment: Just had to deal with that problem in netbeans 8.1. The category 'Mark Occurrences' is no longer language specific! I found it under 'All languages'.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. I was searching for weeks where to change this super annoying yellowish highlight on my dark theme.

Comment: I just had to do this with NetBeans 11, it was under Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors, then *Syntax* and *All Languages* and finally in the list box *Mark Occurrences.*

Comment: For 8.0.2 is letting me change the font color but the background color stays yellowish and doesn't save my custom color.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still bothered with this, in NetBeans 8.0 you will find it under specific JAVA language in Tools-Options-Fonts&Colors-Syntax-Mark Occurences.

Else... very annoying and stressful for a dark theme, indeed.

Comment: `Mark Occurences has been ` appeared after exposing to `all languges`  in dropdown in `syntax` for PHP