# Change highlighting color of auto-highlighted variable names in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, fonts, colors, formatting, highlight

When I move over a class name all the other places that that class name shows up are highlighted.  When I hover over a variable it does the same thing with different places that I have used that variable.  I cannot find where to change that setting in Netbeans.

I changed everything else, but even when I looked under every option in the highlighting section there were none with the same shade of yellow that is seen here:

[image: Two highlighted class names]

There was also nothing in the Syntax or Annotations section that had that shade of yellow.  Is this even a setting that I have control of?

I have Netbeans 7.2.1 if anyone needs to know.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is Language-specific.
You have to go to Syntax > Change a Language and modify the "Mark Ocurrency" color.

Know more:
[How to change the highlight variable color in NetBeans IDE ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709787/how-to-change-the-highlight-variable-color-in-netbeans-ide)

Comment: For the theme I'm using in NetBeans 8.1, this option was listed at the bottom of the Category list as `mark-occurrences`. (I'm using EzObsidian, leaving a comment because I'm not sure if this applies to other themes/versions too.)

Comment: As of Netbeans 8.2 it's listed under Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Syntax Tab.  Leave All Languages selected (I was getting confused as I was changing it to PHP) and you will see Mark Occurrence as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I found this theme generator - helped me with my own color theme.

Below link to the online netbeans color theme generator

[Net Beans theme builder](http://svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder/)

- allow to point - click select code type and assign new colors
- allow to export colors for netbeans (as .zip) aslo for eclipse color theme (.xml)
- Tested on NetBeans 7.4

Comment: Please summarise what that link says briefly.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is too late but it might be useful for someone else ,, 
In Neatbeans Tools >> Options >> Fonts & Colors >> Language (Java) >> Mark occurrences .