# NetBeans Syntax Highlight Class Names

Tags: class, netbeans, syntax, highlight, names

I know to know if i can to Highlight Class Names in NetBeans  8.0.1. Almost IDE has this feature and it's really cool , make the code more readable.

```
class MyClass {

//.....
}

MyClass object = new MyClass();
```

I want to highlight `MyClass`. Even stackoverflow highlight this :((((

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Watch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374894/1966247) This answer may help you, it allows you to create a custom theme for Netbeans and Eclipse

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709787/how-to-change-the-highlight-variable-color-in-netbeans-ide) is another solution to change the highlight color of variable in Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors**
Then in the syntax tab choose **Java** as the language and look for **Class use** and **Class declaration** and change their colors to your liking in the right dropdown of the foreground color.